# Getting new width and height of Bitmap in a TImage if Wrapmode is set to "Fit"

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm loading a `5000x5000` png image onto a TImage with a wrapmode being set to `Fit`. I want to then get the height and width of the bitmap thats being shown in the UI however I seem to only get the original size of the bitmap and not the size of the image thats being shown.

I'm loading the bitmap as follows: `imgMap.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('map_4000_35161.png');`

When resizing the TImage the size of the bitmap being displayed changes so that it can fit inside of the TImage;

How can I get the width and height of the bitmap thats being shown?

I've tried `imgMap.Bitmap.Width`, `imgMap.Bitmap.Canvas.Width` but I only end up getting the original size of 5000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bitmap is your source bitmap, it's not being resized, but rather when it's rendered on the `TImage` it's rendered to fit the `TImage`.  AFAIK, there is no way to get the results of that rendering unless you resize it yourself.

You can get the size of the `TImage`, though.  Is that not enough?  If you are preserving the aspect ratio then it's fairly simple to calculate the size of a rectangle with known aspect ratio and containing boundary.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. I thought there might have been properties to access instead of calculating it myself. I'll do so.